# Azure B2C Custom Policy Not Redirecting Users to Change Password Page on First Login

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm working on integrating Azure B2C with a custom policy to force users to reset their password on their first login. I've set ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn to true in the C# code, but users are not being redirected to the change password page on their initial login. Instead, they are encountering a password expired message.

I've tried implementing the solution provided in the official Azure B2C GitHub repository (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset/policy), but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Below is the relevant C# code and custom policy XML for reference:

C# Code:

```
PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
{
  Password = azureB2cUserCommandModel.Password,
  ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true 
}
```

Custom Policy:

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
      <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
      <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" /> -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organizationName" PartnerClaimType="organizationName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="roleName" PartnerClaimType="roleName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextSignIn" PartnerClaimType="passwordExpired" DefaultValue="false" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
  
  <ClaimType Id="forceChangePasswordNextSignIn">
    <DisplayName>forceChangePasswordNextSignIn</DisplayName>
    <DataType>boolean</DataType>
    <AdminHelpText>Directory property, Whether the user password has expired</AdminHelpText>
  </ClaimType>
  
  <ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <!--Read user objectId by signInName-->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingSignInName">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!--Save the new password to the directory-->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId-ResetNextLogin">
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextSignIn" PartnerClaimType="passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </PersistedClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
  
  <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <!-- <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" /> -->
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <!-- <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" /> -->
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>forceChangePasswordNextSignIn</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <!--Force password reset upon password expiration-->
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForcePasswordResetUponPasswordExpiration" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Phone verification: If MFA is not required, the next three steps (#5-#7) should be removed.
             This step checks whether there's a phone number on record,  for the user. If found, then the user is challenged to verify it. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Save MFA phone number: The precondition verifies whether the user provided a new number in the 
             previous step. If so, then the phone number is stored in the directory for future authentication 
             requests. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>newPhoneNumberEntered</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

I attempted to implement Azure B2C custom policies to force users to reset their password on their first login. I followed the provided documentation and sample code from the official Azure B2C GitHub repository. However, instead of redirecting users to the change password page upon their initial login, they encountered a password expired message. I expected users to be directed to the change password page as per the configured policy.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom policy seems to be configured correctly, but the issue might be related to the orchestration steps in your user journey. Specifically, the step where you check for the `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` claim might not be triggering as expected.

I noticed that you have a precondition in one of your orchestration steps to skip if the `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` claim exists. This might be causing the issue because you want to force the password change only if this claim is present.